# SUMIFS on filtered data?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

I am looking for a way to do a SUMIFS that uses a filtered list. I would like to:

- Grab all the sales from Sheet "Sales" where Group = "Flowers", AND
- Store # on Sheet "Sales" matches the Filtered Store # list on sheet" Report

The following code will work only when there is no filter on the Store #'s:

`=SUMIFS(Sales!C:C,Sales!B:B,"=FLOWERS",Sales!A:A,Report!A:A)`

**Sheet 1 Name = Report**

```
   Row (filtered)      Store # (A)     
====================|==============|
|       21          |      13      |
|       36          |      28      |   
|       81          |      75      |   
|       84          |      78      |
```

**Sheet 2 Name = Sales**

```
Store # (A)    Group (B)      Sales (C)    
===========|==============|=============|
|   21     |   Flowers    |     $100    |
|   36     |   Flowers    |     $200    |   
|   81     |    Bread     |     $500    |   
|   1      |   Flowers    |     $600    | 
|   3      |   Flowers    |     $100    |
|   36     |    Bread     |     $200    |   
|   8      |    Bread     |     $100    |   
|   84     |   Flowers    |     $300    |
```

Is there any way for me to accomplish this? So if when the filtered list changes, the total figure changes, similar to that of a subtotal.

Answer (score 0):

Seems much the easiest way is with a PivotTable: `Group (B)` for FILTERS, `Store # (A)` for ROWS and Sum of `Sales (C)` for VALUES, then filter `Group (B)` to select 'Flowers` and filter rows to suit.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i need to add this to an existing report unfortunately

Comment: I have a "total" row and would like to added above it in a sub total row